# css3 tab in css3 tab issue

Tags: css, menu, tabs

i would like to make a 4 item tab in a 4 item tab. I don't know what messes the function up, but please take a look here.

For one tab with 4 items it is working properly.

```
 <main>
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
<label for="tab1">Codepen</label> 
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab2">Dribbble</label>
<input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab3">Dropbox</label>
<input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab4">Drupal</label>

<section id="content1">
 <main>

<input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
<label for="tab5">Codepen</label>

<input id="tab6" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab6">Dribbble</label>

<input id="tab7" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab7">Dropbox</label>

<input id="tab8" type="radio" name="tabs">
<label for="tab8">Drupal</label>

<section id="content5">
<p>
5
</p>
<p>
5
</p>
</section>

<section id="content6">
  <p>
6
</p>
<p>
6
   </p>
  </section>

 <section id="content7">
  <p>
 asdf
  </p>
 asdf
</section>

<section id="content8">
 <p>
 8
</p>
<p>
 8
</p>
</section>

 </main>
</section>

<section id="content2">
  <p>
2
   </p>
 <p>
 2
  </p>
</section>

<section id="content3">
  <p>
 3
 </p>
 <p>
   3
   </p>
 </section>
  <section id="content4">
 <p>
  4
 </p>
 <p>
 4
 </p>
  </section>
  </main>
```

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX X XXXXXX X XXXXXXX X  XXXXXXX X

Here's a link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/user1010/pen/NzYOqg

Or is it only possible with JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the radio buttons inside content1 a different name from the others. At the moment, clicking on tab5 (for example) is automatically unchecking tab1 because they're in the same group.

In the pen below, I've given tabs 5, 6, 7 and 8 the name `tabs2`.

Working fork of your pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KeobPV